# Moving a command to the background halfway through execution in Bash

Tags: macos, bash, shell, ant

I'm working on a bash script that starts multiple other shell scripts some of which terminate on their own, some of which run indefinitely until terminated. I'm looking for a way to move the execution of one of these subprocesses to the background only after a certain line of output from the script is parsed.

```
#!/bin/bash

sh ./compile.sh 2>&1>/dev/null 
sh ./run.sh 2>&1 | 
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        if [[ $line == *"INFO: Dev App Server is now running"* ]]; then
            osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Build Complete - the build server is now running."' >/dev/null
            break
        fi
    done
read -rsp $'Press any key to "ant clean" and exit...\n' -n1 key
sh ./clean.sh 2>&1>/dev/null
kill -- -$$
```

Specifically, I want to read each line of the stdout and stderr created by run.sh and look for the string `INFO: Dev App Server is now running`. When it's found, I want to notify the user using the osascript, break the loop, and wait for user input before cleaning my build directory and killing the current process group. Right now, piping stdout and stderr to the loop works fine and the osascript runs. However, I'm pretty sure the loop isn't breaking because `Press any key to "ant clean" and exit...\n` never prints and pressing any key triggers neither `clean.sh`, nor the `kill`. My guess as to the problem right now is that the while breaks, but since `run.sh` executes indefinitely until it's killed, the `read` and subsequent code is never reached. I've tried putting the trailing code after the loop in the conditional block, but the read command doesn't print its message to the user then either. Where am I going wrong, and how can I get this script to work as intended?

To provide a little context, I'm on OSX working with `GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`.

Comment: Why do you have a `$` in front of your prompt on line 12?   It's not a variable.

Comment: @rojomoke I actually don't know a ton about the inner workings of the `read` command. I pulled my syntax for that command directly from the second answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134437/press-space-to-continue).

Comment: @rojomoke This is a valid bash syntax for an expanded literal string. It expands backslash sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash waits for all elements of a pipeline. However, it doesn't wait for process substitutions in redirections, so you can rewrite in terms of that:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ $line == *"INFO: Dev App Server is now running"* ]]; then
        osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Build Complete - the build server is now running."' >/dev/null
        cat > serverlog &   # Bonus: read and log the rest in the background
        break
    fi
done  <   <(sh ./run.sh 2>&1)
```

This additionally logs the rest of the output. This is important because most scripts and servers will stop and wait if nothing is reading the output (you can `cat > /dev/null` if you don't care about the output, but just not reading it may make the server unhappy).

Comment: I just figured out a fix just minutes before you posted this, but thanks so much for the response. Your scheme for logging output is quite nice and I think I'll incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!! Another way to get this working is to execute run.sh in an inline group and send it to the background. Then, redirect stderr to stdout for the group, pipe it to the while in another inline group, and break the loop when I parse the message I'm looking for. Note: I've also turned the individual shell scripts into functions in my central bash script. They're not included here for security reasons.

```
#!/bin/bash

compile 2>&1>/dev/null 
{ run & } 2>&1 | {
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        if [[ $line == *"INFO: Dev App Server is now running"* ]]; then
            osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Build Complete - the build server is now running."' >/dev/null && break
        fi
    done
}
read -rsp $'Press any key to "ant clean" and exit...\n' -n1 key
clean 2>&1>/dev/null
kill -- -$$
```